# Combine two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames  `a` and `b` as below

```
a
  Split of Alternate Apr 2017 May 2017 Jun 2017 Jul 2017 Aug 2017 Sep 2017 Oct 2017 Nov 2017 Dec 2017 Jan 2018
1      Black Menthol     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.03     0.03
2              Gold      0.07     0.07     0.08     0.07     0.07     0.07     0.07     0.07     0.07     0.06
3             Green         0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
4               Red      0.09     0.08     0.07     0.09     0.09     0.09     0.08     0.09     0.08     0.06


b

 Split of Alternate Apr 2017 May 2017 Jun 2017 Jul 2017 Aug 2017 Sep 2017 Oct 2017 Nov 2017 Dec 2017 Jan 2018
1      Black Menthol     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.02     0.03     0.03
2  Black Non-Menthol     0.17     0.17     0.18     0.17     0.16     0.16     0.14     0.15     0.16     0.16
3             Green      0.07     0.06     0.07     0.06     0.06     0.06     0.07     0.08     0.09     0.08
4               Red      0.23     0.24     0.25     0.24     0.23     0.23     0.22     0.22     0.20     0.22
```

How can I merge them so that it add red and green value and also show green,menthol and non-menthol.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you just want to add the values? You can do that with `+`

Comment: Can I add two reactive dataframes

Comment: reactive dataframes? Are you making a shiny app? You really need to edit your question to add [MCVE] of your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you're trying to do:

```
library(tidyverse)

ab <- rbind(a,b)

ab %>% group_by(`Split of Alternate`) %>% summarize_all(funs(sum))
```

Comment: I get this error when I do the summarize all `Evaluation error: ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: Make sure your April, May, June... columns are of class `numeric`